# Generating embeddings from a custom hierarchical attention network model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, feature-extraction, word-embedding, attention-model

I took the following model from here
https://www.kaggle.com/code/hsankesara/news-classification-using-han/notebook
and now I want to generate the hierarchical attention embeddings of my dataset.

```
word_input = Input(shape=(max_senten_len,), dtype='int32')
word_sequences = BertEmbeddingLayer()(word_input)
word_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg))(word_sequences)
word_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(200, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg))(word_lstm)
word_att = AttentionWithContext()(word_dense)
wordEncoder = Model(word_input, word_att)[text](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hsankesara/news-classification-using-han/notebook)

#The sentence model that runs first inputing the data 
sent_input = Input(shape=(max_senten_num, max_senten_len), dtype='int32')
sent_encoder = TimeDistributed(wordEncoder)(sent_input) # this calls the wordencoder that encodes the word embeddings and runs it through the first attention layer
sent_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg))(sent_encoder)
sent_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(200, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg))(sent_lstm)
sent_att = AttentionWithContext()(sent_dense)
drpot = Dropout(0.5)(sent_att)
preds = Dense(7, activation='softmax')(drpot)
model = Model(sent_input, preds)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['acc'])
```

The attention with context layer is given below

```
def dot_product(x, kernel):

    if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
        return K.squeeze(K.dot(x, K.expand_dims(kernel)), axis=-1)
    else:
        return K.dot(x, kernel)

class AttentionWithContext(Layer):
    """
    Attention operation, with a context/query vector, for temporal data.
    Supports Masking.
    Follows the work of Yang et al. [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~diyiy/docs/naacl16.pdf]
    "Hierarchical Attention Networks for Document Classification"
    by using a context vector to assist the attention
    # Input shape
        3D tensor with shape: `(samples, steps, features)`.
    # Output shape
        2D tensor with shape: `(samples, features)`.
    How to use:
    Just put it on top of an RNN Layer (GRU/LSTM/SimpleRNN) with return_sequences=True.
    The dimensions are inferred based on the output shape of the RNN.
    Note: The layer has been tested with Keras 2.0.6
    Example:
        model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(AttentionWithContext())
        # next add a Dense layer (for classification/regression) or whatever...
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 W_regularizer=None, u_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, u_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True, **kwargs):

        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')

        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.u_regularizer = regularizers.get(u_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)

        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.u_constraint = constraints.get(u_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)

        self.bias = bias
        super(AttentionWithContext, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3

        self.W = self.add_weight(shape = (input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint)
        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight(shape = (input_shape[-1],),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)

        self.u = self.add_weight(shape = (input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_u'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.u_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.u_constraint)

        super(AttentionWithContext, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        uit = dot_product(x, self.W)

        if self.bias:
            uit += self.b

        uit = K.tanh(uit)
        ait = dot_product(uit, self.u)

        a = K.exp(ait)

        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())

        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]
```

I have tried training the model and after training running an intermediate layer model

```
from tensorflow import keras

new_input = Input(shape=(max_senten_num, max_senten_len), dtype='int32')
with tpu_strategy.scope():
  intermediate_layer_model = keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.layers[4].output)
  intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

I am trying to use this model to genrate hierachical attention embeddings to use as feature in another model but I can't seem to understand how do I generate these embddings. At first, I thought that the prediction of the sent_att layer would be the embeddings that I need, similar to how BERT embeddings are generated (the output of pretrained BERT model on our data), but my senior lead told me that they are different. This is where I am stuck. How else are these embeddings genrated?

Comment: So I am using the model to genrate hierachical attention embeddings to use as feature in another model but I can't seem to understand how do I generate these embddings. At first, I thought that the prediction of the sent_att layer would be the embeddings that I need, similar to how BERT embeddings are generated (the output of pretrained BERT model on our data), but my senior lead told me that they are different. This is where I am stuck. How else are these embeddings genrated?

Comment: Please do not post such info in the comments - *edit & update* your question instead.